# How to compute solvent reorganization energy in Marcus' non-equilibrium approach?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy

I try to solve the following equations for some system solvated in the water. The goal is to obtain value in kcal/mol.  Unfortunately, I cannot reach the desired output. May someone help me?

The  variables are:

```
n = 1 (single electron exchanged)
rA = 3.68Å
rD = 2.90Å
R = 6.58Å
ε∞ = 5.2 F/m
ε0 = 78.408 F/m
```

My try:
[image: Equation]
[image: My]